# PHP Variable Passing in Foreach on same page

Tags: php, html, foreach

I've been struggling this for a while and I simply can't figure this out. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$list = array(
"60002" => array("name" => "Cyan Bubble Color", "info" => array("cost" => "200", "code" => "0x50ebec")),
"65002" => array("name" => "Cyan Name Color", "info" => array("cost" => "150", "code" => "0x00cccc")),
);

foreach($list as $id =>$name) {
echo("<td style=\"vertical-align:middle;\">
      <a href=\"item=$id#confirm\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"modal\">
      Buy</a></td></tr>");
}?>

<html>
  <div class="modal small hide fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Log off before purchase</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p class="error-text"><i class="icon-warning-sign modal-icon"></i>Log off all instances</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="redeem.php?item=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="btn btn-danger">Buy</button></a>
</div>
```

The main issue here is that the $id from the foreeach is not the same as the $id in the div class link. Instead the link is the end value of the foreach list.

Comment: Your code isn't even valid. There's no matching `}`, and you have lines containing HTML with no `echo` statements. Try pasting the actual code for us.

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple modal boxes with multiple id's related to your foreach??? cuz thats not gonna work....you should just do a Jquery link, that when they click on the TR it passes the info to the modal, no need to populate a million modals

Comment: The modal is for when they click on one of the "Buy" links, it pops up a box with a warning message.

Comment: But the id that you want in there, must be from the product you clicked on correct????  In this case...you need to pass it with some jquery...like I show below....because ofcourse its always gonna be the last id if you just echo it with php......

Answer (score 2):

You've defined a variable for use *within* your loop that is already defined *outside*, yet you need to have access to both the exterior `$id` and interior `$id`, correct?

In order to utilize the exterior `$id` variable within your loop, you should rename the variable that tracks the index within your loop to something other than `$id`:

```
foreach($list as $nid =>$name) {
echo("<td style=\"vertical-align:middle;\"><a href=\"item=".$nid."#confirm\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"modal\">Buy</a></td></tr>");

<div class="modal small hide fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<a href="redeem.php?item=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button class="btn btn-danger">Buy</button></a></div>
```

**Update**:

Based on the code updated in the question, it's clear what's happening. The value being originally assigned to `$id` is being overridden by the index assignment in your `foreach` loop. You can still resolve this by renaming the index variable to something other that `$id`:

```
<?php
    $id = 'item_id';

    foreach($list as $nid =>$name) {
        echo("<td style=\"vertical-align:middle;\"><a href=\"item=$nid#confirm\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"modal\">Buy</a></td></tr>");
    } 
?>

<div class="modal small hide fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <a href="redeem.php?item=<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">
            Buy
        </button> 
    </a>
</div>
```

**Update 2:**

Based on the clarifying comments, it seems that you're trying to pass the index variable to `href="redeem.php?item=?id"`. To do this, you'll need to move that particular part of the markup inside your loop:

```
<div class="modal small hide fade" id="confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<?php
foreach($list as $nid =>$name) {
    echo("<td style=\"vertical-align:middle;\">
      <a href=\"item=".$nid."#confirm\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"modal\">
      Buy</a></td></tr>");
    echo("<a href=\"redeem.php?item=$id\"><button class=\"btn btn-danger\">Buy</button></a>");

} ?>

</div>
```

Comment: "_`$id` in the second line is being printed out as a string_": about which line / `$id` you are talking?

Comment: Since the string is enclosed in doublequotes, variables are interpolated, not printed as markup.

Comment: I'd upvote this answer if you removed the misinformation about variable interpolation. You may have a preference for concatenation, but there's nothing wrong with the way he interpolated in the original code. His only problem was the variable name duplication.

Comment: I'm getting a blank value for $id

Comment: Are you assigning a value to `$id` elsewhere in your code? Because your code – in its current entirety – isn't assigning a value to `$id` aside from within the `foreach` loop. I had assumed you were setting it elsewhere.

Comment: I think I miswrote. Let me try to reexplain. When the first "Buy" button is hit from the foreach, the modal pops up and there is another "Buy" button. In your code that I've tried, the modal Buy button is looped.

Comment: The foreeach loop works fine but on the modal, the retrieval of $id is blank.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it...Youll have all those links with id, pass the id to `data`,

then when you click it, trigger some Jquery to retrieve that `id`, and attach to the `href` of the modal....then open the modal.

Something like this....not quite, but its a start.

```
 <?php
 foreach($list as $id =>$name) {
  echo("<td style=\"vertical-align:middle;\">
  <a href=\"item=$id#confirm\" class='buy' data-id=".$id." role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"modal\">
  Buy</a></td></tr>");
   }?>
```

Then some Jquery

```
 $('buy').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  // open your modal here, and pass this id, to the href 
  $('#confirmlink').attr('href', 'redeem.php?item='+id);
  //then open/trigger the modal here..

 });
```

Comment: I'm sorry I have never used Jquery before. How would I use the code you have provided?

Comment: If this answer isnt answered by the time I get home, I'll revise my answer with more complete information  :)  Just leaving work now..........probably about 2 hours.